# Help me identify the adapter plug

Tags: dc, connector, identification

Which type of connector is it?

DC, 4 pins, a plug (cable side, not board side) with 4 female sockets.
It resembles a Kycon 4-pin DC connector but reversed.

It is taken from FSP's AC/DC adapters and can also be found in several laptops.

[image]

Comment: Would you know where I could get an MSI laptop charger with such an adapter ? The only ones I can find online are 100€+ which sounds totally crazy to me :-O

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be a female cable version of a [snap and lock DC power connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Snap_and_lock_DC_power_connectors)

Edit: perhaps it's some sort of custom version of the [KPJX-CM-4S](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KPJX-CM-4S?qs=Qc3PO%252BMSh28KFH2SBAcH1Q%3D%3D)?

Comment: Looks like a crossbred version of KPJX and KPPX indeed.